# Connected Sets Examples

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

(a) Give an example of a connected set $A \subset \Bbb R^n$ such that $\Bbb R^n\setminus A$ is not connected.

(b) Give an example of a compact set $K \subset \Bbb R^n$ which is not connected.

So far my thoughts: 
I'm not sure how a set could satisfy either of these (mostly because I don't know how to think of connected as a concept, besides knowing the technical definitions.)

Comment: Can't you just take $\Bbb R^n - A = \{0\} \cup \{1\}$ and do the same idea for (b)? So $A$ would be the left over set $A = \Bbb R^n - \{0\} \cup \{1\}$, I believe this set is path-connected

Comment: I'm assuming for {0} and {1}, is that the origin and (1, 1, ..., 1)?

Answer (score 0):

Think about an hyperplane for a), as it cuts the space in two open parts. 
For (b), the union of two disjoint closed balls?